# Why is the Facebook business account gets blocked almost immediately after I unblock it?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I'm trying to help set up a Facebook marketing campaign for a small business in the U.S. I did this a few years back, but something has changed since. This time I couldn't find a way to set up a Facebook business account (i.e. Page) without having a personal account.

Since I deleted my personal Facebook a while back, nor that I would use it to set up someone else's business page, I tried to create a personal account for the owner. Real name and everything. And right off the bat it got blocked. (I was using a personal email account for the business owner, that was something like me@personsname.com.) Right off the bat they wanted me to upload the personal picture, provide a cells phone number and then verify it. I did all that. Then they let me create it.

I then created a business page, uploaded a logo and a wide banner on the top. But then when I was in the process of going through other settings, they blocked that account again. It said that to secure my account I need to upload a personal picture. Again! So I did it again. Then it took them about 24 hrs to unblock that account.

So yesterday I was prepping up the business page when right in the middle of saving my data, it repeated this again. Seriously!

Here's the sequence:

1. This page first comes up:

   [image]
2. Then I get a Captcha.

   [image]
3. Then they want me to upload a photo:

   [image]
4. I upload a photo like they want and then I get this page:

   [image]

They never send any updates or anything. After that I have to wait for about 24 hrs for them to unblock it. Only to be blocked again when I log back in after a few hours!

**This has happened 3 times already!**

So what am I doing wrong? (Well, besides using Facebook.)

Comment: whoa. how did you get around this finally ?

Comment: @fixxxer: It's hard to tell what helped. I sent a bunch of messages to their help account. And at some point it stopped blocking me. At the end all I can say -- facebook is really f'ed up!